# Made a Text Browser in QT but the Code Acts Like it Doesn't Exist?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm pretty new to QT so maybe the answer to this question is simple. I'm making a terminal for our freescale car this year which is just a car that autonomously goes around a track. We're using line-scan cameras which give you a line of data 128 pixels long that you refine into either "white" or "black" (edges of the track) values. Last year the team made this terminal in QT which is used for modifying certain coefficients, stopping the motors, and all kinds of stuff through bluetooth. A text browser was used to display what the line cameras see.

Last year they combined the two cameras to create one image, but we're re configuring them this year, and they will produce two different images of the track. Naturally, I need to make two text browsers, one for each camera. Should simply be a case of copying code and changing some names right? Well apparently not.

I placed the text browser in the window using the design gui, named it, and made its settings match the other browser. I went into the code for the main window c file and adapted the code there. For every reference to the other browser I made sure one was an equal line of code for this one. When I was done and went to build the project, it told me that the browser wasn't a member of 'UI::MainWindow,' and pointed me to the ui_mainwindow.h file. So I went into that header and did the same thing in there. But when I built that, it gave me the error:

...\ui_mainwindow.h:1363: error: C2065: 'tb_camera_out_close' : undeclared identifier

How can that be? There doesn't appear to be any other reference to the other text browser and it works fine. How do I go about declaring this? Shouldn't the gui interface have done it for me when I placed it?

Here's the code from the main window's C file that is involved:

```
ui->tb_camera_out->setText(msgs_received[1] + '\n' + ui->tb_camera_out->toPlainText());
ui->tb_camera_out_close->setText(msgs_received[2] + '\n' + ui->tb_camera_out_close->toPlainText());
```

tb_camera_out is the old camera code(I am aware that the toplaintext() part won't work, I'm also attempting to get the text to scroll down instead of up like a track would if you were actually driving but I need to fix this major issue first)

Here's the code from the header that I added:

```
    tb_camera_out = new QTextBrowser(centralWidget);
    tb_camera_out->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("tb_camera_out"));
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(tb_camera_out->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
    tb_camera_out->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
    tb_camera_out->setMinimumSize(QSize(450, 0));
    tb_camera_out->setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 16777215));
    tb_camera_out->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n" "color: rgb(31, 234, 0);"));

    gridLayout_4->addWidget(tb_camera_out, 1, 0, 1, 5);

    tb_camera_out_close = new QTextBrowser(centralWidget);
    tb_camera_out_close->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("tb_camera_out_close"));
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(tb_camera_out_close->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
    tb_camera_out_close->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
    tb_camera_out_close->setMinimumSize(QSize(450, 0));
    tb_camera_out_close->setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 16777215));
    tb_camera_out_close->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n" "color: rgb(31, 234, 0);"));
```

Again, the old code is at the top with the references to tb_camera_out. The stuff I added is associated with tb_camera_out_close.

Comment: Is the next line of your code something like: `gridLayout_4->addWidget(tb_camera_out_close, 2, 0, 1, 5);`

Comment: Pretty sure it was and I just forgot to copy it in, but it looks like qt has undone my changes to that header file. I'm pretty sure that you can't edit the ui header files because qt is supposed to do it for you. In fact it even says at the top that the changes will be lost. I guess the problem is that the ui isn't changing the header file?

Comment: That is correct. The ui header is automatically generated. Have you added the new Textbrowser to a Layout inside the Qt Designer? I never used the Designer so I don`t really now how that works in the Designer. You said that you made the settings match. Look out that there is no unique identifier or Geometric information (Position) that you changed to be the same.

Comment: I seem to have solved the problem. Strangely enough, to fix the errors that were showing up I not only had to edit that header, but I then had to delete it and run qmake to restore it. I then had to delete all the past builds to get the thing to even show up when I ran it. I did use the designer for the UI part. Thanks anyways for your help!

Comment: Glad that you got it working! Have you tried a "rebuild"? A rebuild deletes all files before building the project and should have the same effect.

Comment: Yep I pretty much tried everything at my disposal there in the gui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have solved the problem. Strangely enough, to fix the errors that were showing up I not only had to edit that header, but I then had to delete it and run qmake to restore it. I then had to delete all the past builds to get the thing to even show up when I ran it.